# VBA to Extract all words from several workbooks in a folder and place it in one only column with word count

Tags: excel, vba

I am in need of huge help since I dont know even how to start this..
I have a huge number of workbooks in a folder and I need to extract all words/numbers/symbols from them and place them in another workbook sheet, lets say results.xlsx sheet1, however the words/numbers/symbols must be also counted by number of times used in all the excel documents. The worksheets have the content spread around them, different columns and cells. So the output must be:

```
wordX 1212121
wordY 212121
1000 12121
@we 1221
```

Any idea how to start this? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you have the list of all keywords?

Comment: the words/numbers are spead around all the sheets in the workbooks

Comment: So in other words, you need a count of every single word in the excel sheet?

Comment: @PaulFrancis I update the topic to be more concise :)

Comment: @PaulFrancis Not just one sheet, but many worksbooks with many worksheets inside them

Comment: You want to open every workbook in the folder and then count each unique value of each cell or you want to break apart every individual word from each cell?  Like if cell `A1` says "the fox ate the food" do you want the output to be "the" 2; "fox" 1, "ate" 1, "food" 1 or "the fox ate the food" 1

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I need all results,to break apart every sentence in words. Your example is correct: "the" 2; "fox" 1, "ate" 1, "food" 1 . thank you

Comment: You'll need to start out by figuring out how to list all the files in the folder then use a loop to open them out at a time.  In another loop you'll need to split the contents of every cell.  I would use a dictionary type to keep track of all the unique words.  Good luck.  It sounds like a big task but each part isn't too bad and each part should be pretty easy to google.

Comment: What is your definition of a "word"?  In other words, what characters do you want to exclude/include.  Obviously `space` should be excluded; punctuation should probably be excluded; but what about things like underscores, hyphens, symbols, etc.  What about Unicode characters?  Can we just include letters, digits and underscores (as is the case with Regular Expressions for VBA) or do we need to include something else?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld letters, digits and underscores would do the job. thanks in advance

Comment: You've had some advice as to how to start.  What have you developed?

Answer (score 0):

This one's a scribble, for thought awakening purposes only, I cannot promise it will work in a live environment, in fact I can promise it won't.

```
Dim MyArr() As String, WordArr() As String, Numerosity() As Long, rng As Range, rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*") 'the first cell where there is data

While rng <> rng1 'while it's not the first cell, you'll have to work on it
    Set rng = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=rng) 'after the previous find
    Set MyArr = Split(rng.Value2," ") 'splits cell contents by space, you can further process the set
    For i = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr) 'for each of the words in the set
        Present = False
        For j = LBound(WordArr) To UBound(WordArr) 'check against each element in the full array of words
            If MyArr(i) = WordArr(j) Then 'if there's a match
                Numerosity(j) = Numerosity(j) +1 'you increase the numerosity counter
                Present = True
            End If
        Next j
        If Not Present Then 'if it is yet to be submitted
            ReDim Preserve WordArr 'khmm, there's probably someone who knows
            WordArr(UBound(WordArr)) = MyArr(i) 'append it to the end
            ReDim Preserve Numerosity 'again
            Numerosity(UBound(Numerosity)) = 1
        End If
    Next i
Wend
```